# Complexity of multiplying bivariate polynomials of degree n

Tags: polynomials, multiplication

Let $P(X,Y)$ and $Q(X,Y)$ be two bivariate polynomials of degree at most $n$.
Using $O(n^2)$ FFTs, we can compute the product $PQ$ in time $O(n^3\log n)$.

**Q:** Is there a faster algorithm to compute $PQ$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to describe how to evaluate $P(\omega^u,\omega^v)$ at the roots of unity.  Suppose $P(X,Y)=\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j} X^i Y^j$.  Let

$$F_{b,c}(X,Y) = \sum_{i,j} a_{2i+b,2j+c} X^i Y^j$$

where the sum is over all $i,j$ with $i\le n/2, j \le n/2$.  Then

$$P(X,Y) = F_{0,0}(X^2, Y^2) + Y F_{0,1}(X^2, Y^2) + X F_{1,0}(X^2, Y^2) + XY F_{1,1}(X^2, Y^2).$$

Therefore you can evaluate $P(\omega^u,\omega^v)$ at the $n^2 $ roots of unity by evaluating each $F_{b,c}(\omega^{2u},\omega^{2v})$ at the $(n/2)^2$ roots of unity.  This leads to a recursive algorithm whose running time is given by

$$T(n) = 4 T(n/2) + O(n^2),$$

which has the solution $T(n) = O(n^2 \log n)$.  This immediately leads to an algorithm to compute the product $P(X,Y) Q(X,Y)$, analogous to the standard algorithm for (univariate) polynomial multiplication with DFTs, by evaluating at the roots of unity, multiplying pointwise, and then applying the inverse DFT.  I'll let you fill in the details from here.

Comment: Thank you, I should have tried it myself! I also checked that the inverse DFT yields the coefficients of $PQ$, which is an important final step.

Comment: By the way, it's probably a typo, but I believe the recurrence relation for the complexity should read $T(n) = 4T(n/2) + O(n^2)$, but I can't edit your post to add a single character.

Comment: @GBat, oops!  Thank you, fixed.